# Spring boot + mongoDB filtering by enum

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, filter, enums

So I have a class called Location that stores data about it in mongoDB as well as locationType, which is Enum that has OFFICE and EVENT types.
Currently in the Location repository I have a filter written like this:

```
@Query("{'locationType':?0}")
List<Location>findByType(LocationType type);
```

but it does not really work when trying to filter by enum in postman and was thinking if I could somehow filter it with string but then it converts it to enum type?
If yes, then how?

Service class in which I call the repository that extends MongoRepository<Location,String> in which the filtering is done:

```
@Override
public List<Location> filterType(LocationType type){
    return locationRepository.findByType(type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the filter to this:

```
@Query("{'locationType':?0}")
```

`List<Location>findByType(String locationType);`